# Show that the set of $x$ such that $x$ majorizes $y$ is convex

Tags: statistics, convex-analysis, order-statistics, quantum-information

I have this question involving Majorization :

show that $x$ majorizes $y$ if and only if

$$\sum_{j=1}^{d}\max(x_j-t,0)\leq\sum_{j=1}^{d}\max(y_j-t,0)$$
and
$$\sum_{j=1}^{d}x_j=\sum_{j=1}^{d}y_j$$

for all real values of $t$, where $d$ is the dimension of $x$ and $y$.

I can do this bit just fine by picking values of $t$ and showing that one implies the other. But the next part is:

Use the previous exercise to show that the set of $x$ such that $x$ majorizes $y$ is convex.

From which I'm not entirely sure how to proceed. Do I have to define a specific form of y?

*Exercise was taken from Nielsen and Chuang "Quantum Computation and Information" section 12.5.1*

Comment: The function $\mathrm{max}(x-t,0)$ is convex in $x$ for each $t.$

Comment: so how would I explicitly show that $\sum\lambda_i x_i = x_j$? which is what I interpreted as the definition of a convex set?

Comment: Suppose $x^{1}$ and $x^{2}$ are two vectors that majorize $y.$ Then if you can show that $\alpha x^{1}+(1-\alpha)x^{2}$ also majorizes $y,$ for any $\alpha\in[0,1],$ you're done. This condition for a convex set seems weaker, but they're actually equivalent.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean in your comment, though, so please let me know if I've missed the mark.

Comment: I was more getting at the idea that you could use the previously shown equivalence in the definition of majorization to show that x is convex. I accept the alternative definition for a convex set, but I was looking for a way to use the previous part of the question to show that the vector x itself is convex, in that its elements make up a convex set. Also, to use that definition I feel like I'd have to show that it's true, which may be a bit of a long way round. I feel like there's some way of wrangling the equivalent definition of majorization shown into the basic definition of a convex set.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a convex set $S$ is that for any two points inside it, $x^{1}$ and $x^{2},$ and $\alpha\in[0,1],$ $\alpha x^{1}+(1-\alpha)x^{2}\in S.$ We want to show that the set $S=\{x\text{ majorizes }y\}$ is convex using the characterization of majorization above. Noting that $\max(x-t,0)$ is convex in $x$ for each fixed $t,$ and since $x^{1}$ and $x^{2}$ majorize $y,$ we see that \begin{align*}\sum_{j=1}^{d}\max(\alpha x^{1}_{j}+(1-\alpha)x^{2}_{j}-t,0)&\leq \sum_{j=1}^{d}\alpha\max(x^{1}_{j}-t,0)+(1-\alpha)\max(x^{2}_{j}-t,0)\\&\leq \sum_{j=1}^{d}\alpha\max(y_{j}-t,0)+(1-\alpha)\max(y_{j}-t,0)\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{d}\max(y_{j}-t,0).\end{align*} Lastly, again since $x^{1},x^{2}$ majorize $y$, $\sum_{j=1}^{d}\alpha x_{j}^{1}+(1-\alpha)x_{j}^{2}=\alpha\left(\sum_{j=1}^{d}y_{j}\right)+(1-\alpha)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{d}y_{j}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{d}y_{j}.$ This proves that $\alpha x^{1}+(1-\alpha)x^{2}$ majorizes $y,$ hence belongs to $S$, which completes the proof.